# How to make sure that the bot automatically puts the specified reaction on each message in a specific channel?

Tags: python, discord.py

```py
def green_check(reaction, user):
        return str(reaction.emoji) == '' and user != bot.user

    try:
        reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=3600.0, check=green_check)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await concept_msg.delete()
        await ctx.author.send("No moderator responded, wait some time and try again.")
        return
    else:
        concept_embed_dict = concept_embed.to_dict()
```

Comment: Your question is currently unclear, and I can't really tell what you want to achieve. Can you include some more code and describe the problem in detail? What is the expected behavior and the actual behavior?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want your message to have an initial reaction by your bot, you can use [`Message.add_reaction()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=add_reaction#discord.Message.add_reaction).

```
await concept_msg.add_reaction('')
```